# Yoneda Lemma and foundations

Tags: category-theory, foundations, yoneda-lemma

Yoneda Lemma says that, for a locally small category $\mathcal{C}$, an object $A$ in $\mathcal{C}$ and a functor $F:\mathcal{C}^{op}\to \textbf{Set}$, the natural transformations $[Hom(-,A):F]$ is in one-to-one correspondence with elements of $F(A)$.

My question is the following:

1. $\textit{A priori}$, we do not know that the collection $[Hom(-,A):F]$ is.  Now we show a "bijection" to $F(A)$.  How does it imply that the collection $[Hom(-,A):F]$ is a set.

If the above question does not make sense, then I try to frame it in another fashion.

2. For doing mathematics we need to consider primitive undefined objects and their "properties".  Mathematicians argue that foundations can be built in many ways like-

   - sets and $\in$ (Well, wasn't this the plan)
   - sets and $f$ (function) (Leinster's $\textit{Basic Category Theory}$)
   - types (friend told this to me)

So what are the objects we are considering in Category theory. If we take an arbitrary collection of morphisms, when can we say it is a set or not.  If it is not a set, how is its properties different from that of a set.

If this is vague question, specfically considering Yoneda Lemma, how can we say that $[Hom(-,A):F]$ is a set.

Comment: Considering the (small/large)-sets foundations, the collection $\text{Nat}(\text{hom}_C(a,-),F)$ _is_ a set (small or large), and not because of Yoneda Lemma.

Comment: Yoneda Lemma shows that $\text{Nat}(\text{hom}_C(a,-),F)$ is _isomorphic_ to a small set, but it may not be small itself.

Comment: What do you mean by "isomorphic"?

Comment: Two sets $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic, if there exist functions $f\colon X\to Y$ and $g\colon Y\to X$, such that $g\circ f=id(X)$ and $f\circ g=id(Y)$.

Comment: Of course, it is equivalet to say that there exists a bijection $f\colon X\to Y$.

Comment: Which foundations are you talking about.  Is there a reference for the same?

Comment: It is actually the ordinary $\text{ZF}$ plus the assumption of the existense of  a universe. The best reference for a start is Mac Lane's "Categories for the working mathematician", chapter 1, paragraph 6 ("Foundations").